# MS Excel: COUNTIFS doesn't work when A criteria cell is empty

Tags: excel-formula

I would really appreciate some help whit my problem. I tried to read about it but nothing I found works.

I am trying to pull some data from another spreadsheet based on multiple criteria /entered in cells B4:B6/.

- B4 - Customer Name
- B5 - FROM Date
- B6 - TO Date

**I want to be able to extract data based on only one cell or any combination of them.**
*/B4&B5,B4&B6,B5&B6,B4&B5&B6/*

I tried using the following formula:

`COUNTIFS(JOBS!$C$1:$C$10000,$B$4,JOBS!$L$1:$L$10000,">="&$B$5,JOBS!$L$1:$L$10000,"<="&$B$6)`

The formula works fine if all cells /B4:B6/ are filled but returns `#NUM!` if one is empty.

I tried:

`COUNTIF(JOBS!$C$1:$C$10000,$B$4)+COUNTIF(JOBS!$L$1:$L$10000,">="&$B$5)+COUNTIF(JOBS!$L$1:$L$10000,"<="&$B$6)`

The formula works fine if only one cell /B4:B6/ is filled but the data overlaps if 2 or more are filed.

Comment: It seems like you have your ranges backwards... `JOBS!$C$1:$C$10000` first, then `$B$4` second?

Comment: Hi BigBen, I took the function from another place and I noticed that but when I tried to correct it did not work. Returns N/A. It works like that though, I don't know why.

Comment: The range should come first, then the criterion... can you [edit] your question with your revised attempt?

Comment: Done. Although it doesn't work this way it is better if I write it correctly so no one gets misled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wildcards when empty:

```
=COUNTIFS(JOBS!$C$1:$C$10000,IF($B$4="","*",$B$4),JOBS!$L$1:$L$10000,">="&IF($B$5="",0,$B$5),JOBS!$L$1:$L$10000,"<="&IF($B$6="",99999,$B$6))
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea @Scott Craner

Answer (score 0):

In fact the formula I am using looks very weird. The positions of criteria and range appeared to be switched.

The original formula looks like this:

`COUNTIFS($B$4,JOBS!$C$1:$C$10000,$B$5,<="&JOBS!$L$1:$L$10000,$B$6,">="&JOBS!$L$1:$L$10000)`

And it is working fine, apart from the problem I mentioned in the title.

Thanks to the idea Scott gave me I have rewritten my formula and now it looks like this:
`COUNTIFS($B$4,IF($B$4="","",JOBS!$C$1:$C$10000),$B$5,IF($B$5="","","<="&JOBS!$L$1:$L$10000),$B$6,IF($B$6="","",">="&JOBS!$L$1:$L$10000))`

Although, I am not sure if this is the right way the formula should be written, it works great and my problem is now solved.